# $\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{1-2x}} \leq e^{\frac{x^2}{1-2x}}$ where $0<x<1/2$

Tags: analysis, statistics

Anyone have insights how to come up with this inequality? I can prove this but need some insights how people come up with this. 
It's Chapter 1 question 2(b) in notes http://www-math.mit.edu/~rigollet/PDFs/RigNotes17.pdf

Comment: The question you are asking seems to be different from what is mentioned in notes (check lhs). Although the notes will imply your inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:
(Use $2x = t$). Taking logs, on one side is  $-1/2 \log(1-t)$, on the other a fraction in $t$. The Taylor exansion at $0$ for LHS is know, for RHS follows easily from decomposing into simple fractions. Now compare the coefficients and notice those on RHS larger for every power of $t$.

Comment: Any insights how to come up with this directly?

Comment: @Ken: You can use $e^s \ge 1+s$, but then you have to show another inequality involving the square root. That's probably why he choose this particular one, although it is in a way suboptimal, as you can see if you deal with logs and power series.

Comment: Thanks:) I'll take a look